# How to configure wildfly to use EclipseLink?

Tags: java, eclipselink, wildfly, wildfly-8

i have installed wildfly 8.1 and because i have already a project configured to use EclipseLink, i have tried to configure wildfly to use it.

However, it always gives the same error :

```
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: JBAS011466: PersistenceProvider '
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
' not found
 at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.lookupProvider(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:990)
 at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.addPuService(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:258)
 at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.handleWarDeployment(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:191)
 at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.deploy(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:126)
 at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.deploy(PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.java:52)
 at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 ... 5 more
```

I have followed the instructions of the [official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingEclipseLink), but nothing changed. I have added the eclipseLink's jar to "modules\system\layers\base\org\eclipse\persistence\main"
and the module.xml :

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.eclipse.persistence">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jipijapa-eclipselink-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="eclipselink.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="asm.asm"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
        <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        <module name="org.antlr"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
        <module name="org.dom4j"/>
        <module name="org.javassist"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.spi"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.vfs"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Do you know what is the problem ?

Tks

**Edit** :
My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="AppPu">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/H2Ds</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: can you show me persistence.xml?

Comment: i edited my post and added my persistence.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem!

in fact, I have a composite unit, all persistence.xml are correct, but the persistence.xml which declared the composite unit was a bad statement of the provider:

```
<provider>
   org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
</provider>
```

replaced by :

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

and now work fine.

Comment: There is no difference between the two ways: with newlines or without them. So that is not what solved your problem.

Comment: for me, it makes a big difference! Now I deploy without error. For fun I have retried to insert a line break after provider's tag and I reproduce the error!

Comment: Very strange. But looking on the stacktrace it make sense

Answer (score 14):

New lines in provider section of persistence.xml won't work (how could it help?).
Wildfly hasn't got provided eclipseLink implementation in libs. To fix this follow this steps:

1. Download eclipselink.jar (or copy from your maven repo)
2. Copy it to
   destination :
   ...Wildfly\modules\system\layers\base\org\eclipse\persistence\main
3. Edit module.xml (same path). Add section 
   `<resource-root path="eclipselink.jar"><filter><exclude path="javax/**" /></filter></resource-root>`

After server restart everything should work.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingEclipseLink

Answer (score 3):

You need to add provider to persistence-unit in your `persistence.xml`:

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Comment: oops ! juste an error in copy / past, but my persistence.xml contains the declaration of the provider ! I solved the problem, I make a response to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

The official documentaiton on how to configure the eclipselin module, and the required system property to active the vfs acrhieve factory impl are both given here:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingEclipseLink

For the module do something as:

> ```
> <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.eclipse.persistence">
>     <resources>
>         <resource-root path="jipijapa-eclipselink-10.0.0.Final.jar"/>
>         <resource-root path="eclipselink.jar">           
>            <filter>
>               <exclude path="javax/**" />
>            </filter>
>         </resource-root>
>     </resources>
>
>     <dependencies>
>         <module name="asm.asm"/>
>         <module name="javax.api"/>
>         <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
>         <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
>         <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
>         <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
>         <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
>         <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
>         <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
>         <module name="org.antlr"/>
>         <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
>         <module name="org.dom4j"/>
>         <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.spi"/>
>         <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
>         <module name="org.jboss.vfs"/>
>     </dependencies>
> </module>
> ```

For the system property do something as:

> ```
> <system-properties>
>    ...
>    <property name="eclipselink.archive.factory" value="org.jipijapa.eclipselink.JBossArchiveFactoryImpl"/>
> </system-properties>
> ```

Finally, do not start adding to your persistence.xml any container sepcific properties like:

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="JBoss" />
```

This is completely wrong.
Wildfly is already taking care of puting the proper target server platform in its:

org.jipijapa.eclipselink.EclipseLinkPersistenceProviderAdaptor

Here is a sample of code from their class:

> ```
>   @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
>     @Override
>     public void addProviderProperties(Map properties, PersistenceUnitMetadata pu) {
>         if (!pu.getProperties().containsKey(ECLIPSELINK_TARGET_SERVER)) {
>             properties.put(ECLIPSELINK_TARGET_SERVER, WildFlyServerPlatform.class.getName());
>             properties.put(ECLIPSELINK_ARCHIVE_FACTORY, JBossArchiveFactoryImpl.class.getName());
>             properties.put(ECLIPSELINK_LOGGING_LOGGER, JBossLogger.class.getName());
>         }
>     }
> ```

YOu might want to make sure you debug this class, to make sure it gets invoked and makes your dynamic persistence unit properties all proper.
But do not mess around with persistence.xml properties that are specific to the container. Wildfly is doing this properly and they add them themselves.

So just follow their documentation, that is the best advice.

Answer (score 0):

in EAP with a servicepack there is the trap that the `org.eclipse.persistence` module might actually be in the `.overlays/` tree (`modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/`).